# NSwag generate single client class

Tags: swagger, code-generation, swashbuckle, nswag, nswagstudio

When using `NSwagStudio` for generating C# client code (not in file) it generates the way that only one client class and corresponding interface is getting generated with all controllers methods in them.
However when trying to do the same thing with `NSwag.MSBuild` it generates separate partial classes/interfaces for each controller.

Here is the `nswag.json`:

```
{
"openApiToCSharpClient": {
  "clientBaseClass": "BillingBaseClient",
  "configurationClass": "ConnectionOptions",
  "generateClientClasses": true,
  "generateClientInterfaces": true,
  "clientBaseInterface": null,
  "injectHttpClient": true,
  "disposeHttpClient": true,
  "protectedMethods": [
  ],
  "generateExceptionClasses": true,
  "exceptionClass": "ApiException",
  "wrapDtoExceptions": true,
  "useHttpClientCreationMethod": false,
  "httpClientType": "System.Net.Http.HttpClient",
  "useHttpRequestMessageCreationMethod": true,
  "useBaseUrl": true,
  "generateBaseUrlProperty": false,
  "generateSyncMethods": false,
  "exposeJsonSerializerSettings": false,
  "clientClassAccessModifier": "public",
  "typeAccessModifier": "public",
  "generateContractsOutput": false,
  "contractsNamespace": null,
  "contractsOutputFilePath": null,
  "parameterDateTimeFormat": "s",
  "parameterDateFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd",
  "generateUpdateJsonSerializerSettingsMethod": true,
  "useRequestAndResponseSerializationSettings": false,
  "serializeTypeInformation": false,
  "queryNullValue": "",
  "className": "BillingClient",
  "operationGenerationMode": "MultipleClientsFromOperationId",
  "additionalNamespaceUsages": [
  ],
  "additionalContractNamespaceUsages": [
  ],
  "generateOptionalParameters": true,
  "generateJsonMethods": true,
  "enforceFlagEnums": false,
  "parameterArrayType": "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable",
  "parameterDictionaryType": "System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary",
  "responseArrayType": "System.Collections.Generic.ICollection",
  "responseDictionaryType": "System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary",
  "wrapResponses": false,
  "wrapResponseMethods": [
  ],
  "generateResponseClasses": true,
  "responseClass": "SwaggerResponse",
  "namespace": "ServiceTitan.Billing.Api.Client",
  "requiredPropertiesMustBeDefined": true,
  "dateType": "System.DateTimeOffset",
  "jsonConverters": null,
  "anyType": "object",
  "dateTimeType": "System.DateTimeOffset",
  "timeType": "System.TimeSpan",
  "timeSpanType": "System.TimeSpan",
  "arrayType": "System.Collections.Generic.ICollection",
  "arrayInstanceType": "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection",
  "dictionaryType": "System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary",
  "dictionaryInstanceType": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary",
  "arrayBaseType": "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection",
  "dictionaryBaseType": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary",
  "classStyle": "Poco",
  "generateDefaultValues": true,
  "generateDataAnnotations": true,
  "excludedTypeNames": [
  ],
  "excludedParameterNames": [
  ],
  "handleReferences": false,
  "generateImmutableArrayProperties": false,
  "generateImmutableDictionaryProperties": false,
  "jsonSerializerSettingsTransformationMethod": null,
  "inlineNamedArrays": false,
  "inlineNamedDictionaries": false,
  "inlineNamedTuples": true,
  "inlineNamedAny": false,
  "generateDtoTypes": true,
  "generateOptionalPropertiesAsNullable": false,
  "templateDirectory": null,
  "typeNameGeneratorType": null,
  "propertyNameGeneratorType": null,
  "enumNameGeneratorType": null,
  "serviceHost": null,
  "serviceSchemes": null,
  "output": "BillingClient.g.cs"
  }
}
```

So which option am I missing for telling NSwag to generate single class/interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option you need to change is `operationGenerationMode` which you have already in your nswag.json file, but you need to change its value to `SingleClientFromOperationId` if you want to have one interface for multiple controllers. `MultipleClientsFromOperationId` which is what you currently have set, will generate a class per controller.

Comment: I use MultipleClientsFromOperationId , but nswag generate only one client.